# arranging <div>s around a polygon (HTML, css, .ejs)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to arrange some rectangular div components around a regular polygon.  Basically one of the long sides of the divs will be coincident with a line segment around the polygon.

In the final code, I'll use .ejs (since the number of sides of the polygon is dynamic, 3-10 sides).  In my "quick and dirty" testing I'm doing a triangle in just HTML and CSS to get the math right.

I have a "very close" solution already and am wondering how to get it "exact" and am also wondering why my geometry intuition is so far off.

**HTML and CSS**:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.rotatedA {
  transform: translateY(-60px) translateX(-35px) rotate(300deg);
  background-color: blue;
}


.rotatedB {
  transform: translateY(-60px) translateX(35px)  rotate(60deg);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="basic.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Normal</div>
    <div class="rotatedA">Rotated</div>
    <div class="rotatedB">Rotated</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The first attempt I rotated "A" by 60 and "B" by -60 and did a translateY equal to the div height.  When that did not work I played around with it.
On this last attempt (close but not perfect since the rotations won't give an integer) it seems like the Y adjustment is 1.5x (item height + cos(60)) but the X adjustment is 1/2 of sin(60) (I don't understand why).

Since my results aren't going to be an integer number of pixels what is the correct way to do this?  Also, I don't understand why my geometry is so off (I could understand sin(60) but 1/2(sin(60)) doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Are you looking for this maybe: https://jsfiddle.net/4k2ubq6h/ ? I don't think there's a straightforward formula for the positions of those rectangles, especially not if you aren't positioning them by their center.

Comment: Not sure why you posted an answer as a comment.  Your answer IS (codewise) what I am looking for.  I'm also confused about the geometry (your answer doesn't explain that part).  You also showed that the CSS / HTML will allow non-integer pixels (which I wrongly thought they wouldn't)

Comment: I'm moving the origin of the transformation above the rectangle (to the center of the triangle's in-circle), so now all I need to do is to rotate it.

Comment: If you post your comment as an answer (rather than a comment) I can give it credit.  I'm working on the pentagon version and having trouble with it, if you're willing maybe you could fill me in on the geometry for it (I have part of it but not all of it)- though probably we should do that by email rather than by forum.

Comment: I only post answers if the question is a useful addition to the website that can be found by and will help future users. This problem is very specific and primarily about maths, that's why I'm hesitant to post an answer. Anyway, give me a few minutes and I'll take a stab at the pentagon version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mathematical way; the number and dimensions are read by the script, then the divs are arranged accordingly. I also made sure that the wrapper container has the correct dimensions so it can be used with other elements:

```js
function arrange(wrapper) {
  wrapper.style.position = "relative";
  const rects = Array.from(wrapper.children);

  const n = rects.length;
  /* dimensions of a rectangle */
  const bb = rects[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  const a = bb.width;
  const h = bb.height;
  
  /* incircle radius of regular polygon */
  const r = a * 0.5 / Math.tan(Math.PI / n);

  /* radius of outer circle */
  const bigR = Math.sqrt((r + h) * (r + h) + a * a / 4);

  rects.forEach((rect, i) => {
    const angle = i * (360 / n);
    if (angle) rect.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
    rect.style.position = angle ? "absolute" : "relative";
    rect.style.marginBottom = bigR + r + "px";
    rect.style.transformOrigin = `${a/2}px ${-r}px`;
    rect.style.left = bigR - a / 2 + "px";
    rect.style.top = bigR + r + "px";
  });
  if (window.getComputedStyle(wrapper).display == "inline-block")
    wrapper.style.width = 2 * bigR + "px";
}

arrange(document.querySelector('#polygon'));
```

```css
#polygon {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

#polygon div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="polygon">
  <div>Normal</div>
  <div>Rotated</div>
  <div>Rotated</div>
  <div>Rotated</div>
  <div>Rotated</div>
  <div>Rotated</div>
  <div>Rotated</div>
</div>
```

The basic idea is to

1. calculate the in-circle's radius of the polygon based on the width of a rectangle
2. set `transform-origin` accordingly centered and above the first rectangle
3. arrange the others by rotating them
4. (do more calculations so the wrapper element encompasses everything exactly)

Comment: I'm going to give credit for this- though I didn't actually want someone else to do the programming, mainly I am/was having trouble with the geometry.  But this does everything I asked about so I'll accept it as correct.